# Given a $k$-partite graph $G$ formed from the union of a set of $k$-cliques, is $G$ a comparability graph?

Tags: graph-theory, order-theory, simplicial-complex

Are all $k$-partite graphs with a pure clique complex of dimension $k-1$ transitively orientable?

A transitive orientation is as assignment of a direction to each edge in $G$ such that if $v \rightarrow w$ and $w \rightarrow x$ are in the graph, then $v \rightarrow x$ is too. Any graph with such an orientation is called a comparability graph

Edit: Does it make a difference if $k$ is even?

Comment: You've asked two completely differently phrased questions in the title and the body of your question, and didn't define your terms. In my answers below, I've guessed at what you mean, but I could be completely wrong (if, for instance, your terminology doesn't quite match up with Wikipedia's). Please try to make your questions easier to understand :(

Comment: I appreciate the answer, I added a follow-up if you're familiar with the answer. Are the questions not synonymous? A k-partite graph which has a pure clique complex of dimension k-1 is a more precise way to say a k-partite graph formed from the union of k-cliques. Also comparability graphs are precisely those graphs with a transitive orientation. I felt this terminology was all standard enough not to need re-defining

Comment: I did need to look up "pure clique complex" and "comparability graph". If the questions are synonymous, that's good, but I wasn't sure. Anyway, I've edited my answer to address all $k$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Given a $k$-partite graph which is the union of $k$-cliques, is there an orientation such that whenever $u \to v$ and $v \to w$ are edges, $u \to w$ is an edge?

The answer is no. For example, take the tripartite graph with tripartition $$\{a_1,a_2,a_3\} \cup \{b_1, b_2, b_3\} \cup \{c_1, c_2, c_3\}$$ which is the union of four triangles: the triangles with vertices $$\{a_1,b_1,c_1\} \quad \{a_2,b_2,c_2\} \quad \{a_3,b_3,c_3\} \quad \{a_1, b_2, c_3\}.$$
Here's why. The three parts are symmetric, so without loss of generality, we can assume that we orient the last triangle as $a_1 \to b_2, a_1 \to c_3, b_2 \to c_3$. Then there are two cases:

- If edge $a_2b_2$ is oriented $a_2 \to b_2$, then we have edges $a_2 \to b_2$ and $b_2 \to c_3$, but can't have the edge $a_2 \to c_3$ (because $a_2c_3$ is not an edge of the original graph).
- If edge $a_2b_2$ is oriented $b_2 \to a_2$, then we have edges $a_1 \to b_2$ and $b_2 \to a_2$, but can't have the edge $a_1 \to a_2$ (because $a_1a_2$ is not an edge of the original graph).

So this graph does not have a transitive orientation.

---

The same construction generalizes to all $k>2$: starting with $k^2$ vertices $\{ v_{ij} : 1 \le i,j \le k\}$, we take the $k$ cliques on sets $\{v_{i1}, \dots, v_{ik}\}$, and the "diagonal" clique $\{v_{11}, v_{22}, \dots, v_{kk}\}$.

No matter how we orient the diagonal clique, there will be some vertex $v_{ii}$ that's neither the source nor the sink of that orientation. In that case, any way to orient the clique $\{v_{i1}, v_{i2}, \dots, v_{in}\}$ will give us a failure of transitivity: a directed path of the form $v_{hh} \to v_{ii} \to v_{ij}$ or $v_{ij} \to v_{ii} \to v_{hh}$ with no edge to complete it.

(For that matter, this $k$-partite graph has the tripartite graph from earlier as an induced subgraph, which immediately tells us that it's also a counterexample.)

For $k=2$, of course, any bipartite graph which is the union of edges (that is, any bipartite graph) has a transitive orientation, where we orient all the edges to point from one part to the other.